# Spatial Reference and Area/Length Attributes relationship

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, polygon-creation, coordinate-system

I currently allow users to add a shapefile in. From the shapefile, allow the user to generate a new layer base on the polygons from the shapefile's polygon they imported.

Generating the new polygon and putting them into my own layer is no longer a problem, however, I see the Area/Area_Length attribute to be different between my new and old polygon.

Only difference is I projected the Map's spatial reference to the new polygon, instead of using the layer's spatial reference.

Do you guys know if that is the reason behind the different attributes?

Code:

```
foreach (IPolygon polygon in polygons)
{
   //Need to project to the map spatial reference
   polygon.Project(IMap.SpatialReference);

   //Generate a new polygon
   newPolygon = new Polygon() as IPolygon;

   ((Polygon)newPolygon).AddPointCollection((IPointCollection)polygon);

   //Add the feature
   subcatchmentFeature = new SubcatchmentFeature(newPolygon);
   AddFeature(subcatchmentFeature);
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the differences in Area/Perimeter relationships between projected and unprojected data?